# jupyter server dfdata.to_clipboard from remote to local machine. how?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe say `dfdata` in a **jupyter server notebook running on a remote machine)**.

I want to access the dataframe in the remote machine memory to my local machine, say to paste the `dfdata` to Excel.

Normally (when the notebook server is running locally), I do `dfdata.to_clipboard()`  to copy the dataframe to clipboard and now able to paste it to Excel.

However, since the `dfdata` is now on the remote machine, the `dfdata.to_clipboard()` does not have the copy of the dataframe in clipboard.

How to make this work, i.e. copy paste dataframe from remote machine to locally running Excel, Textfile, etc.? Any alternative methods, if `to_clipboard()` by design will not work across remote server due to any security restrictions / limitations.

Comment: why not `df.to_excel('/path/to/file.xlsx', index=False)`?

Comment: i will try this to see if it works. However, `to_clipboard` is so convenient... to paste across many places... including reading it in another notebook, paste to text file, email, word, gvim, etc. I only provided Excel as an example. I really wish that `to_clipboard` can be made to work on remote server as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[I wrote a Jupyter nbextension to do this](https://github.com/njwhite/jupyter-clipboard) (installation instructions in the README).

It overwrites Panda's `pandas.io.clipboard.copy` & `pandas.io.clipboard.clipboard_set` (which is an embedded copy of [pyperclip](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip)) to send messages to the Jupyter frontend via the [Comm](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/comms.html#opening-a-comm-from-the-kernel) mechanism. I had to add a simple bootstrap-based UI that pops up when the client-side JS receives a message, as browsers [won't let you](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/issues/270#issuecomment-228770685) push data onto the system clipboard without explicit user interaction (security!).

Comment: thank u for this.. however, my teammate tested this and he said it didn't work.. does it only work with Jupyterhub... NOT with normal jupyter notebook server.. ?

Comment: @ihightower it should work - I've pushed another change to fix startup race conditions. If it still doesn't work for you, could you attach the console debug logs from your browser to [an issue in the github repo](https://github.com/njwhite/jupyter-clipboard/issues)? Thanks!

Comment: hi this works now. thank you. the issue was pypaperclip was not installed aldy. 3 qstns: 1) is there any possibility to do ``` pd.read_clipboard() ```from client clipboard excel copy to be read into the server data frame, 2) will there be any perf issue i.e. will it grind to halt after say copying 50,000 rows.. i will try this later., 3) is the original to_clipboard and yr extension comparable in perf, any limitations that you see? if yes, how to rever to original to_clipboard for some specific cases..? thanks again.

Comment: continuing from above questions.. 4) is there any limit to the no. of rows that can be copied.. i see only 1000 rows max that is copied and cannot do more. 5) how does the data come to the browser.. as i don't see any network traffic in chrome console logs. Would appreciate your explanation on all the questions. Thank you.

Comment: i have moved to jupyter lab. Is there a solution for Jupyter Lab to copy remote clipboard to local computer. I can't find any solution yet. Please help.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative you can use `copydf` - [github](https://github.com/conceptualio/copydf) and [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/copydf/).

This should be as simple as `pip install copydf`.

Then in your jupyter session:

```
from copydf import copyDF
copyDf( df )
```

Comment: it works thanks great!. from server clipboard to local. any solution (for local clipboard to server) e.g. if i copy a table in excel.. and use df = pd.read_clipboard() it should show the excel table data in df. possible?

Comment: This could be possible by posting the content of the clipboard to the server but this would require a service listening for that post. It seems challenging to do without modifying the read_clipboard func. Would be curious if anyone else knows of a way thought.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another terminal session connected to the same remote server, you can try getting the clipboard system to output to the terminal.

I tried `xclip -o` in another ssh session (after calling `df.to_clipboard()` in the notebook) and it printed the contents of my DataFrame to the terminal.  I was able to copy that text and paste it to Google Sheets successfully, split correctly into columns.

It may depend on what's installed on the server.  There is apparently another clipboard system called `xsel`, but `xclip` worked for me on Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Comment: thank you. i haven't tried this. but do you have solution for windows 10 machine (client) to windows server (server). i am not familiar with the xclip.. and does it support both to_clipboard (server clipboard to client) and read_clipboard (client clipboard to server).