# Copy to clipboard in jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, clipboard

I'd like to implement a clipboard copy in a jupyter notebok.

The jupyter notebook is running remotely, thus I cannot use `pandas.to_clipboard` or `pyperclip` and I have to use `javascript`

This is what I came up with:

```
def js_code_copy(content)
    return """
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var tmp_textbox = document.createElement('input');
body.appendChild(tmp_textbox);
tmp_textbox.setAttribute('value', '{content}');
tmp_textbox.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
body.removeChild(tmp_textbox);
""".format(content=content.replace("'", '\\'+"'"))
```

Note that the code does what it's supposed to if I run it in my browser's console.

However, if I run it in jupyter with:

```
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
content = "boom"
display(Javascript(js_code_copy("Copy me to clipboard")))
```

Nothing works,

Any ideas ?

Comment: Which clipboard are you attempting to copy to? do you want the information on the machine you are working on or the remote machine that is hosting the jupyter instance?

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://stackoverflow.com/q/46547299/6206578

Comment: @SethWahle, I am trying to set the clipboard of the machine running the browser (not the machine hosting jupyter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For security reasons, your browser disables the use of `document.execCommand` if the method wasn't called as a result of a user action, e.g clicking a button.

Since you're injecting and running Javascript on the page, this is not considered a user action.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to run the code in a headless browser in the background.